# React Prime Org chart

Tags: reactjs, primereact, orgchart

I use react prime org chart to do a vizualization of a company Structure. Is there any way or a algorithem that I can use to scale up and down my company structure according to the container size?

```
    return (
      <div className="visualization-main-container">
        <div className="tree-container">
        <div className="card overflow-x-auto ">
            <OrganizationChart value={data} nodeTemplate={nodeTemplate} />
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```